# How to limit decimals displayed in angular FormControl?

Tags: angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I saw tons of custom code to manually modify the values or init values, but is there any native way in angular reactive forms to configure the way numbers are displayed in inputs?
Without modifying the actual value of the model, because my variables are numbers and all the answers I found convert to string the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing parseFloat, toFixed (so to string), and parseFloat again.

```
newValue = Number.parseFloat(Number.parseFloat(newValue).toFixed(2));
```

I'm not sure it's the most robust or efficient solution, but it's simple code at least.